# Logging SQL queries

Tags: mysql, database, go, logging

Our go code is organized like this.

We have MySQL struct

```
type MySQL struct {
    mysqlDB *sql.DB
    db      sqlbuilder.Database
    logger  service.logger
}
```

Our repository

```
type ServiceRepo struct {
    db     *database.MySQL
    logger servicelogger.Logger
}
```

and then we use these structs to issue sql queries like this

```
statement, err := s.db.RawDatabase().PrepareContext(ctx, query)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer statement.Close()

_, err = statement.ExecContext(ctx, value1)
```

Now, what i want to do is to log every query that is being executed. How can i do this? I want to do client side logging.

Comment: *"Now, what i want to do is to log every query that is being executed. How can i do this?"* Stop reinventing the wheel ?  See [The General Query Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html) .. *"I want to do client side logging. "* Why?  Client logging which uses prepared statements is much harder to do

Comment: Otherwise the most easy way i geuss is to make a MySQL proxy on the local client where you proxy the prepared statement query request, log it and send it to the MySQL server and proxy the response back to the program

Comment: Your problem is essentially the context, right? How to get the information from it... because all other info is right there.